# Why does Subsonic create a class for my CoreData table as CoreDatum?

Tags: subsonic, subsonic3

As the question says... does Subsonic not like the word Data so it changes it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Data is the plural of Datum. SubSonic generates classes with singular names, so converts the table name CoreData to the class name CoreDatum.

Comment: I believe there is a setting to stop subsonic renaming plural tables. Well there was in 2.0 "fixPluralClassNames"

Comment: Check the T4 files  - I believe it's in the _Setting.tt where we set the name of the tables (either there, or in _SQLServer.ttt - or whichever provider you use). We call a class called "Inflector" that handles the pluralization feature - overwrite that as you will...